# wordpress get_categories count also custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

on my home page i want to present how many posts are for each category. so i use get_categories->count for that. but i have a news custom post type. each news item is associated with a category. so how can i exclude the custom post type from the count?

here is the code i have:

```
$args = array(
    'type'  => 'post',
    'child_of'  => 0,
    'parent'  => '',
    'orderby'  => 'name',
    'order'  => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'  => 0,
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'exclude' => array(1,8),
    'include' => '',
    'number' => '',
    'taxonomy'  => array('category'),
    'pad_counts' => true
  );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
```

then i use within the loop: echo $category->count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this should help you out. The following code will list all of your post categories with their respective post counts, omitting the News CPT posts from the count total.

```
<?php $cats = get_categories();  // Get categories ?>

<?php if ($cats) : ?>
    <ul>
    <?php // Loop through categories to print name and count excluding CPTs ?>
    <?php foreach ($cats as $cat) { 

        // Create a query for the category to determine the number of posts
        $category_id= $cat->term_id;

        $cat_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'cat' => $category_id
        ) );
        $count = $cat_query->found_posts;

        // Print each category with it's count as a list item
        echo "<li>" . $cat->name . " (" . $count . ")</li>";

    } ?>

    <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data  ?> 
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering. it is what I wanted exactly, and it works. but when I checked the codex they actually suggest not to use query_posts. is there an alternative to get the same result? [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)[link]

Comment: I went ahead and utilized wp_query() instead of query_posts(). Everything should still work the same way. Let me know! ~ Kory

Comment: I changes it like so: $wp_query("cat=$category_id&posts_per_page=-1"); and got this error: Fatal error: Function name must be a string

Comment: That won't work, you should use the edited code that I posted above.